# Grails get a property by is name

Tags: grails, groovy

Let's say I have an class like this:

```
class Termin {
    String someName
}
```

Then an object

```
object a = new Termin();
```

and a variable

```
String something = a.someName;
```

How can I get the name of the property someName from the class if I only have the variable something?

Comment: erm, what?! you have a `String` and want to know from which field it was assigned? how should that work?!

Comment: I just want to get the field name

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: I send a parameter to a function that checks if a query was updated then I need to write to the output which field was updated

Comment: What if `Termin` had a field called `someName` and another `otherName` and the value of both was 'Jacob'. What do you expect would happen then?

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way should be:

```
a."${something}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String something = ...
String propertyName = a.properties.entrySet().find { 
   return it.value == something
}?.key
```

Comment: It returns boolean values. I want to know the name of the field!

Comment: You are checking by value. I just want to get the name not depending on the value of the variable. Just like to trace it back to where it belongs :)

Comment: I cannot understand what you want. ypu have `something`, and asked how to find source field. but don't want to use `something`, right?

Comment: Because I don't want to check by the value

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you want at this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that unless you check each property value from the `Termin` object as per @Igor Artamonov answer. The value you assigned to `String something` doesn't yield something like a reference to the original object the property belonged.

You can try to work with `MetaProperty` explicitly, but it will get clumsy:

```
class Termin {
  String name
}

t = new Termin(name: "john doe")

def something = t.metaClass.properties.find { it.name == "name" }

assert something.getProperty(t) == "john doe"
assert something.field.name == "name"
```